# Problem on an integral

Tags: calculus

Ok, so I know the fundamental theorem of calculus. However, this problem has a limit of $x^2$ instead of $x$. How do I solve it and what does it really mean ?
[image]

How do I use the chain rule here ? It's a bit confusing

Comment: The problem is already solved.  It's unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

We have $F(x) = \int_\pi^x \cot^2 t\,dt$, which by the FTC gives us $F'(x) = \cot^2x$.

Then we have $\int_\pi^{x^2}\cot^2t\,dt$, which we can write as $F(x^2)$. So we have an inner function of $u(x) = x^2$, and we want to differentiate $F(u)$ with respect to $x$. That's exactly what the chain rule allows us to do:
$$
\frac{d}{dx} F(u) = F'(u)\cdot u'(x)\\
= \cot^2u\cdot 2x = 2x\cot^2x^2
$$

Comment: Alright. I understood the solution. What does it mean when my upper limit is x² and not x?

Comment: @NigelGoveas It doesn't mean anything special. It just means that when $x = 4$, you're integrating from $\pi$ to $16$, not from $\pi$ to $4$. Of course, if this is from some application, and not just from an abstract integration exercise it might carry some significance.

Answer (score 0):

You are integrating with respect to $t$ though. Then you just apply the fundamental theorem of calculus where $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}F(\pi) =0$ since it is constant. The equality after that uses the chain rule.